# Implementing Comparator class in Java

Tags: java

I am new to java. I have not understood one thing while implementing the following code:

```
public class Demo 
{
class DemoComparator implements Comparator<Board>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Board A, Board B) { 
        return A.f()-B.f();
    }
PriorityQueue<Board>Q = new PriorityQueue<>(10, new DemoComparator());
```

}

Here, Board is a class which I haven't shown and f() is a function that returns an integer value. My question is if I write:

```
Q.add(element1);
Q.add(element2);
Q.add(element3);
```

where, element1,element2 and element3 are of type Board and  have their own f values returned from their respective f() function.

Will element1,element2 and element3 be stored in the priority queue according to their f values considering any increasing or decreasing order? and when the line: **return A.f()-B.f();** will be called?

Comment: why don't you consider `Comparable<T>` instead of `Comparator<T>`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the elements will be ordered by the Comparator you pass the constructor.  From the docs:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

The head of the queue is the item with the lowest value.  The comparator will be called on the constructor or when you call add() from the collection interface or the offer() method from the queue interface.  Just look at the source code:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/PriorityQueue.java#267

Or write a little test that proves it's happening.

Comment: will the comparator be called when I call add() from the second time and later? @Robert Moskal

Answer (score 1):

If the `f` values are themselves `Comparable` you may want to use

```
return A.f().compareTo(B.f());
```

This would ensure that your data is sorted by the natural ordering of `f`, otherwise you can simply define the Comparator functionality yourself as you did in the provided example.